# Regex not working in Python for one element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex

I am trying to select only certain block of text from the following list and uotput the results to a dataframe:

```
test = [
  'bbb', 'soup test0:88', 'axx', 'xzz', 'one test4: 34',
  'COPYSUCCESSFUL: https://test.test2.nugget.com/f02/01/test1.csv',
  'COPYSUCCESSFUL: https://test.test3.nugget.com/f02/01/test3.csv',
  'one test4: 66'
]
```

the code I am using:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = ['bbb', 'soup test0:88', 'axx', 'xzz', 'one test4: 34','COPYSUCCESSFUL: https://test.test2.nugget.com/f02/01/test1.csv',
        'COPYSUCCESSFUL: https://test.test3.nugget.com/f02/01/test3.csv', 'one test4: 66']

# regex pattern to extract the text after "COPYSUCCESSFUL:" and before "'"
pattern1 = re.compile(r"COPYSUCCESSFUL:\s*(.*?)(?=')")

# regex pattern to extract the value after "one test4:"
pattern2 = re.compile(r"one test4:\s*(\d+)")

# regex pattern to extract the value after "soup test0:"
pattern3 = re.compile(r"soup test0:\s*(\d+)")

# create empty lists to store the extracted data
copysuccessful = []
one_test4 = []
soup_test0 = []

# iterate through the list and extract the required data using regular expressions
for item in test:
    match1 = pattern1.search(item)
    match2 = pattern2.search(item)
    match3 = pattern3.search(item)
    
    if match1:
        copysuccessful.append(match1.group(1))
    else:
        copysuccessful.append(np.nan)
    if match2:
        one_test4.append(match2.group(1))
    else:
        one_test4.append(np.nan)
    if match3:
        soup_test0.append(match3.group(1))
    else:
        soup_test0.append(np.nan)

# create a dictionary to store the extracted data
data = {'COPYSUCCESSFUL': copysuccessful, 'one test4': one_test4, 'soup test0': soup_test0}

# create a pandas dataframe from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# print the dataframe
print(df)
```

however the output I am getting is:

```
   COPYSUCCESSFUL one test4 soup test0
0             NaN       NaN        NaN
1             NaN       NaN         88
2             NaN       NaN        NaN
3             NaN       NaN        NaN
4             NaN        34        NaN
5             NaN       NaN        NaN
6             NaN       NaN        NaN
7             NaN        66        NaN
```

so no output for column COPYSUCCESSFUL. I have used some regex testers and all seems ok, so I don't understand why nothing is in the output of the column.
I would expect both "https://test.test2.nugget.com/f02/01/test1.csv" & "https://test.test3.nugget.com/f02/01/test3.csv" to be present in the column.

ANy help is wholeheartedly welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no output for column COPYSUCCESSFUL. I have used some regex testers and all seems ok, so I don't understand why nothing is in the output of the column

From your regex `COPYSUCCESSFUL:\s*(.*?)(?=')` it seems you assumed your strings would literally end in with a `'` symbol. But they don't.
When you write `'abc'` in python, you define a string with content `abc`. The quotes are only syntax, not actual data.
Since your regex expects a `'` that isn't in your strings, you end up without any matches.

Looking at your sample data, I'd assume you can just use the regex `^COPYSUCCESSFUL:\s*(.*)` instead.

#### By the way

Since you are looking for multiple keywords like `COPYSUCCESSFUL`, `one test4` and so on, it might be easier and faster to use a more flexible approach than a big line of `if else` statements:

```
def  all_nan():
  return [np.nan] * len(items)

keywords = {
  'COPYSUCCESSFUL': all_nan(),
  'one test4':      all_nan(),
  'soup test0':     all_nan()
}
for item in test:
  key, _, value = re.partition(':')
  if key in keywords:
    keywords[key].append(value.lstrip())
```